# Getting rid of a favicon completely

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, favicon

I am a webdev that has a website but it displays a white file as a favicon (in chrome and maybe other browsers too) however I would like to completely get rid of the favicon, how could I do this?

Comment: Use a transparent 1x1 pixel image as the favicon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a transparent favicon of any size, which will be effectively invisible to the end user. If you need a transparent favicon generator, http://www.favicon.cc/ should do the trick.